# Socket server does not get the 2nd request

Tags: .net, sockets

I use VS 2008 to implement a server which gets a socket connection from a client.
I used MSDN sample code for this, and it really works for me first time.
My information from the client author is that before first request it tries to handshake and then to send its first request. I really get it well. 
Afterwards I send the the response to client which get it as well.
But now my problem starts:
The client starts to send me requests but I get nothing!!!
I'm not sure about my implementation, since in MSDN sample there is only one request.
Can anyone explain what should the difference be between getting the 1st request and the 2nd one? Should I use Socket.Accept() for each request, or after I have the retrieved socket from Socket.Accept() function I simply use Socket.Receive()?

My code is based on MSDN sample is here:

```
listener.Bind(localEndPoint);

listener.Listen(10);

// Start listening for connections.

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");

// Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.

Socket handler = listener.Accept();

data = null;

SocketError errorCode;

// An incoming connection needs to be processed.

while (true)

{

bytes =new byte[1024];

handler.ReceiveTimeout = 2000;

int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes,0,1024,0,out errorCode);

data +=Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);


Console.WriteLine("Text received : {0}", data);

string answer = "my answer to client";

// Echo the data back to the client.

byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(answer);

handler.Send(msg);


 }
```

My results are first time I get some data in bytesRec and send the response to client. Then I do not get again anything to bytesRec , but the recieved is aborted due to timed out error.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you mind formatting your code so that it is readable?

Answer (score 1):

You call `Socket.Receive()` as many times as it takes to receive each message, and then carry on calling it to receive the next message, and so on.

Note that calls of `Receive()` at one end of the connection are **not** in one-one correspondence to calls of `Send()` at the other end<sup>1</sup>. If you're wanting to send "messages", it's usually up to you to implement this over the top of sockets - by e.g. prefixing each message with its length, using fixed length messages, etc or use a higher level networking primitive.

---

<sup>1</sup>So a single call to `Receive()` may only retrieve part of a message, or retrieve multiple messages, or retrieve the end of one message, one or more complete messages, and the start of another message, etc.

Comment: Socket.Recieve() is good after I get the data from the client. The point here that no data is caught in my socket... So can you please explain about the Accept vs Recieve?

Comment: @gelly - if you want us to diagnose/debug your code, you're going to have to show us some of it. Perhaps if you can create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and show us that, we can help you.

Comment: Edit my question with the code. Thank you.